# Android background task for calling API every 5 seconds

Tags: java, android, api, android-service, background-process

I want to control my Android App via my API. 
For that I need to have a background task that calls the API every 5 seconds (but it must know when the API has finished, then wait 5 seconds and call again).

Then if there is a new data on the API, Control the App aspect such as(play video, stop video. play video playlist)

My question is, What is the best solution to implement these requirements.

I really appreciate any help guys thanks again. 
P.S. I am novice to android.

**More info on - Controlling the app's aspects**.

I have to conduct a Video player test on 300 tablets. all at the same time.

So the App will listen/wait for a command from the API. 
the API command by defaut will be false.

When there is a new command (i.e. play video 1). the app will execute it.

Some commends the API will pass can be:
Play Video, Stop Video. Play all Video. Exit the App.

Therefore the API Listener method has to be always running in the back end, if there is a new command than execute it.

Thank guys.

Comment: if it in foreground process you just can use java timer

Answer (score 1):

I propose that you use a [Timer](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html) scheduling the timer to run every 5 seconds (5000 milliseconds since the schedule method of Timers takes the cycle rate in milliseconds) and then have a boolean mechanism to know when the API is finished where you'd then use `Timer.cancel` and if it was 5 seconds do schedule again, that is if by "it must know when the API has finished, then wait 5 seconds and call again" you mean for it to fetch info then wait 5 seconds until it is done then fetch it again. Otherwise all you need to do is make a timer cycling every 5 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Runnable refresh;
   refresh = new Runnable() {               
            public void run() {


            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "C'Mom no hands!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                    handler.postDelayed(refresh, 3000);


            }
        };
        handler.post(refresh);
```

Comment: can I run this outside of an Activity? . So this method will always be running whenever activity is active on the app. ? Thank you for your help.

Comment: where ever you want to stop thread use this: handler.removeCallbacks(interval);    Thank you!!

Comment: you want every 5 seconds your method have to call right.

Comment: yes. I just try it on onCreate and cant get it to work